# Convert hex value string to Binary string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to convert `000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717` hex value to it's binary format (to a string of binary), but following code throws an exception if either value being too big or too small. Why is that?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim binstring As String
        Dim hexstring As String = "000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717"
        binstring = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexstring, 16), 2)

        T5.Text = binstring
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code includes this expression `Convert.ToInt32(hexstring, 16)` which tries to convert your hex string to a 32-bit integer. The string in your example converts to a number that is far more than 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32` converts to, unsurprisingly, an `Int32`.

The maximum value of an `Int32` is [`Int32.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), which is 2,147,483,647.

The number in your code, 0x117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717, is much larger than that (6,860,217,587,554,922,525,607,992,740,653,361,396,256,930,700,588,249,487,127 in decimal), so it doesn't come close to fitting.

**EDIT**

You didn't ask for help actually converting this, but here's a hint: each hex digit represents four binary digits (because 16 is 2^4). You can convert each digit of the hexadecimal individually and just concatenate them. In other words, 0xF1 = 11110001 in binary, because 0xF = 1111 and 0x1 = 0001. Just be careful to keep the trailing zeros you need.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment on your question, your hex string is too long to convert to a 32-bit integer, which your code is trying to do. I would approach this by looping through the characters of the hex string and converting each to a binary string of length 4 (padded on the left with "0").

```
Dim hexstring As String = "000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717"
Dim bin As New Text.StringBuilder
For Each ch As Char In hexstring
    bin.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(ch, 16), 2).PadLeft(4, "0"c))
Next
T5.Text = bin.ToString
```